# Filter json result with datetime - exclude weekends - Python

Tags: python, json, fixer.io

Consider this code:

```
def getHistoricRates():
rates = []
response = urlopen('http://data.fixer.io/api/1999-01-01?access_key=my_key')
data = response.read()
rdata = json.loads(data.decode(), parse_float=float) 
rates_from_rdata = rdata.get('rates', {})
for rate_symbol in ['USD', 'GBP', 'HKD', 'AUD']:
    try:
        rates.append(rates_from_rdata[rate_symbol])

    except KeyError:
        logging.warning('rate for {} not found in rdata'.format(rate_symbol)) 
        pass
return rates
```

This code, takes from `response` an API response, with a series of currency exchange rates, from 1999 until now, what I need, is to understand, how can I filter this data, by taking the `date` from all of these years, but, excluding weekends.

The response from this api url is something like this:

```
"success":true,"timestamp":915235199,"historical":true,
"base":"EUR","date":"1999-01-01",
"rates":{"ANG":2.086282,"AUD":1.918776,... other currencies}
```

I don't know if I'm explaining myself, I'm getting all the historical data, but I need to actually get this, excluding weekends.

I know that `datetime` has a `isweekday` function, but I'm not really sure on how to use it in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what I am understanding is correct - you want rates corresponding to only dates that lie on a weekday. (Correct me if I am wrong)

In such a case, you can use the datetime [day.weekday()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) method.

> day.weekday() explanation -  Return the day of the week as an
>   integer, where    Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6. For example, date(2002,
>   12, 4).weekday() == 2

So, usage would be something like this -

```
date_str = "1999-01-01"
if datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str,"%Y-%b-%d").weekday()<5: #Converting to a datetime object after which weekday() method call will return <5 for a weekday
    rates = getHistoricRates(date_str) #pass the date_str in the function
```

[Refer here](http://strftime.org/) for date string formatting that I have done in the above code.

Comment: Thank You, this seems to do the trick, but I'm getting ´ValueError: time data '1999-01-01' does not match format '%Y-%b-%d', seems to be Okay with me, does that parameter need also the hour and minutes?
´

Comment: @NeoVe My bad. Try "%Y-%m-%d". You can refer to this link to understand what "%Y-%m-%d" exactly means - strftime.org

Answer (score 2):

> from https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html :
>
> date.weekday()
>   Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday
>   is 0 and Sunday is 6. For example, date(2002, 12, 4).weekday() == 2, a
>   Wednesday. See also isoweekday().

So I guess you could do something like:

```
import datetime
dataYear = "year from your data"
dataMonth = "Month from your data"
dataDay = "Day from your data"
dateToCheck = datetime.date(dataYear,dataMonth,dataDay)
if(dateToCheck.weekday() == 5 or dateToCheck.weekday() == 6):
     isWeekend = true
```